# Ubuntu 20.04 Software Update crashes

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, updates, python

Brand new sys76 Thelio desktop with ubuntu 20.04

During installation at the point of linking online account (google) the install hung and I had to hard reboot. The install seemed to start over upon reboot, and this time linking online accounts skipped. The installation completed and all seemed well. However, when I try to launch Software Update it crashes. I rebooted and tried launching Software Update again and same thing.

It would appear until I repair this I won't be able to install or upgrade software. Any help in how to fix this would be most appreciated. Thank you.

The following is from the applications log:

```
12:10:32 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.debian.apt: Permission denied
12:10:32 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.debian.apt: Permission denied
12:10:32 update-manager:     trans = yield self.client.update_cache(defer=True)
12:10:32 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 66, in update
12:10:32 update-manager:     result = gen.throw(excep)
12:10:32 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 483, in _inline_callbacks
12:10:32 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:32 update-manager: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
12:10:32 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name
12:10:32 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:32 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:32 update-manager:     return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:32 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
12:10:32 update-manager:     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:32 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
12:10:32 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.debian.apt: Permission denied
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
12:10:30 update-manager:     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
12:10:30 update-manager:     return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
12:10:30 update-manager:     daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
12:10:30 update-manager:     result = gen.send(result)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
12:10:30 update-manager:     raise self.value.with_traceback(self.traceback)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 130, in raise_exception
12:10:30 update-manager:     error.raise_exception()
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1594, in on_error
12:10:30 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.debian.apt: Permission denied
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
12:10:30 update-manager:     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
12:10:30 update-manager:     return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
12:10:30 update-manager:     daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
12:10:30 update-manager:     result = gen.send(result)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
12:10:30 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.debian.apt: Permission denied
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
12:10:30 update-manager:     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
12:10:30 update-manager:     return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
12:10:30 update-manager:     daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
12:10:30 update-manager:     result = gen.send(result)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
12:10:30 update-manager: Traceback (most recent call last):
12:10:30 update-manager: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
12:10:30 update-manager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name
12:10:30 update-manager:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
12:10:30 update-manager:     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
12:10:30 update-manager:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
```

Comment: Hey Rich Johns! Are you able to update using terminal? Try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. If there are any errors, copy and paste them in the question. If you're replying to my comment, don't forget to tag me like this: @technastic_tc

Comment: @technastic_tc thanks for responding. I did test running update via the terminal, but what I did was run the update-manager command. This also incurred an error. In looking at the terminal output (which I no longer have) and the logs I was able to take a reasonable guess at what to reinstall to fix this.  I will answer my own question below with the detail. Thanks again for your willingness to help.

Comment: You're welcome Rich Jones. I'll be looking forward to your answer. Don't forget to accept your answer after 48 hours. Do read this article: https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @RandomPerson Great! Your  workaround worked! I could update everything from the terminal. However, does this mean that the `update-manager` might got corrupted? Could `sudo apt purge update-manager && sudo apt install update-manager` be helpful?

Comment: @NiladriSarkar Thanks for the compliment. I'm not sure if your `update-manager` is corrupted. I or maybe someone else could help you out if you post a new question with all the relevant details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, after some research and examining the logs I decided to take a shot at reinstalling a few things. To that end I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbus python-dbus python3-dbus
```

Fortunately this seemed to clear up the problem.

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 21.10 except I had to remove the 'python-dbus' as it was failing and said there was 'no candidate'.